# SQL Count Number of "Employees" With "Salary"

Tags: mysql

I've got a query that I'd like to write. The content of which is similar to what I am posting below:

```
SELECT id, name, position, salary, 
    (SELECT COUNT(salary 's') FROM employees WHERE s = salary) As NumberofEmployeesWithSalary
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

Essentially, what I am after is the ability to sum the number of employees with a particular, dynamically-defined salary (so that I am able to form a percentage off it). I've wracked my brain on Google, dev.MySQL, and SO trying to find an answer.

I don't know if this is possible. I may just need to separate out each "salary type" into a separate `COUNT` query.

So, for instance, if my data contains:

```
Salary
------
30000
30000
30000
40000
40000
50000
```

I'd like to get back 3 for 30000, 2 for 40000, etc., specifically with the intent of using that result for a value in another query to grab a percentage.

Comment: Look into the 'group by' mysql documentation

Comment: Does COUNT(DISTINCT salary) work?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker, I've heard that `GROUP BY` is bad practice (on another SO post). Is that true?

Comment: I never heard of that. Can you show where you saw that.

Comment: @MoisheLipsker, I can't find it! I have been searching for a while.

Comment: Just add a group by in your request, google it, its easy to understand.

Comment: Well if it solves your problem,  well that's what the function was made for... If you can't find it in multiple places that its bad practice,  its possible it is fine. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT salary, count(*)  As NumberofEmployeesWithSalary FROM employees
WHERE hire_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY salary;
```

Try the above query and you should get something like this

```
Salary  NumberofEmployeesWithSalary
------  --------------------------
30000              3
40000              2
50000              1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
COUNT(2.02.)
FROM
employees
WHERE
salary != (
SELECT
salary
FROM
employees
WHERE
MONTH(end_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(end_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
)
AND end_date > CURRENT_DATE()